# IFTTT realtime api

Tags: real-time, webhooks, ifttt

I am trying to set up a realtime api.
https://platform.ifttt.com/docs/api_reference#realtime-api

Now we are working on a simple polling.
I do it according to the instructions

It says that:

> "With IFTTT's Realtime API, you can have Applets involving
> user-oriented triggers from your service run near-instantly."

I send a request by specifying the trigger id in the request body. I receive a result with a status of 200. But the service does not make a request to update the data near-instantly. A minute or five minutes pass. Almost the same as without the realtime api. Is that how it should be? Am I missing something?

I send this:

```
headers:
{'IFTTT-Service-Key': '***', 'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'X-Request-ID': '24814446-eeca-47bc-a44b-3a1d90569868', 'Accept': 'application/ json', 'Content-Type': 'application/ json'}
```

json:

```
{'data': [{'trigger_identity': '***'}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had three services. However, only one was allowed. After removing unnecessary services, everything worked.
[image]